# How to access a Gatling scenario from a different simulation file in Java

Tags: java, scala, simulation, gatling, scenarios

I previously used Gatling/Scala but have now moved on to Gatling/Java and I am trying to run a scenario that is described in a file found in: **/assignments/performance/scenarios/LoginScenario/TeacherLoginFlow.java**.

I am trying to do this from the file **/assignments/performance/simulations/BaseSimulation.java**.

**TeacherLoginFlow** looks like this:

```
package com.hmhco.assignments.performance.scenarios.LoginScenario;

public class TeacherLoginFlow {


    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap();

    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL) // Here is the root for all relative URLs
            .shareConnections();

    FeederBuilder teachers = csv("data/teachers.csv").circular();


    ScenarioBuilder LoginFlow = scenario("auth-flow").repeat(AUTH_FLOW_REPEAT).on(
            feed(teachers)
                    .exec(session -> {


etc
```

And I am trying to trigger this **"LoginFlow"** scenario in the BaseSimulation by importing it as:

`import com.hmhco.assignments.performance.scenarios.LoginScenario.TeacherLoginFlow;`

And then feed it a csv file of teacher logins like this:

```
package com.hmhco.assignments.performance.simulations;

...
...

import com.hmhco.assignments.performance.scenarios.LoginScenario.TeacherLoginFlow;


public class BaseSimulation extends Simulation {

    FeederBuilder teachers = csv("data/teachers.csv").circular();

    ScenarioBuilder loginTeacherUsers = scenario("auth-flow").exec(

            feed(teachers)
                    .exec(TeacherLoginFlow.LoginFlow);
    );




   // log.info("Simulation is about to start!");

    SetUp testSetup = setUp(
            loginTeacherUsers.injectOpen(rampUsers(NUMBER_OF_USERS).during(RAMP_UP))
    ).maxDuration(MAX_DURATION);
```

I am getting the error **'LoginFlow' is not public in 'com.hmhco.assignments.performance.scenarios.LoginScenario.TeacherLoginFlow'. Cannot be accessed from outside package**

Does anyone know how I can trigger the LoginFlow scenario that is written in TeacherLoginFlow.java from inside BaseSimulation.java?

Answer (score 0):

That's just a plain Java question.
Make LoginFlow `public static final` and then call `TeacherLoginFlow.LoginFlow`.

Comment: Something like "    public static final ScenarioBuilder LoginFlow = scenario("auth-flow")...."?